# Twitch @bot.event doesn't do anything

Tags: python, api, twitch, twitch-api

I am trying to make a twitch bot, but I seem to be unable to use `bot.event` for some reason.

If I use `@bot.command`, it works perfectly and sends a response in chat:

```
@bot.command(name='test')
async def test_command(ctx):
    await ctx.send("this is a test response")
```

But if I use, `@bot.event` I get no response, even though its supposed to print the name and content to the console:

```
@bot.event
async def event_ready(ctx):
    print(ctx.author)
    print(ctx.content)
    await bot.handle_commands(ctx)
```

My set-up:

```
from twitchio.ext import commands
from twitchio.client import Client

bot = commands.Bot(
    token='oauth:my_oath_key',
    client_id='230bszhh7p16oneij97dv6qgvcspuv',
    nick='robo',
    prefix='!',
    initial_channels=['the_mass_man'],
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run()
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, my code is directly from a tutorial and I haven't changed anything about it other than my token/id/channel.

Comment: Try `@bot.event()`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher It also doesn't seem to work.